# Getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I'm getting FileNotFoundError:

```
list_file = open(file="liss.txt", mode="r")

print(list_file.readable())

list_file.close()
```

Note: Files are in the same folder and it's able to read the file with full pathname.

Comment: check your current directory has liss.txt or not

Comment: Are you running Python from that same folder?

Comment: Yes my .txt file is in the same folder with my .py file

Comment: Are you sure that there's no any typo? Have you tried `open("liss.txt", "r")` or even reading the file  `open("liss.txt", "r").read()`?

Comment: Try using the full pathname to your file

Comment: @DhanaD. Yes I've firstly written `open("liss.txt", "r")` but it came out with same error.

Comment: @DarkKnight It's reading the file with full pathname but not without it. I want to solve that.

Comment: Are you starting your python script from the directory it is in or are you starting it with an absolute path?

Comment: @dgw I'm starting my python script from the directory it is in.

Comment: Maybe for debugging you can try: `os.system('ls')` or `os.system('dir')`.

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'liss.txt')`